# Adding multiple S3 paths to glue crawler with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, aws-glue, terraform-provider-aws

I'm building out some infrastructure in AWS with Terraform. I have several S3 buckets created and want a Glue crawler to crawl these buckets once per hour. My Terraform Glue catalog db, role, and policy all build fine but when I try to create the crawler resource by adding four S3 paths to the `s3_target{}` portion of the crawler, I get a failure:

```
resource "aws_glue_crawler" "datalake_crawler" {
  database_name = "${var.glue_db_name}"
  name          = "${var.crawler_name}"
  role          = "${aws_iam_role.glue.id}" 

  s3_target {
#    count = "${length(var.data_source_path)}"
    path = "${var.data_source_path}"#"${formatlist("%s", var.data_source_path)}"
  }
}
```

This causes an error:

```
Error: aws_glue_crawler.datalake_crawler: s3_target.0.path must be a single value, not a list
```

I have tried adding a `count` statement in the `s3_target` but this fails. I have also tried adding

```
"${formatlist("%s", var.data_source_path)}"
```

in the `path` argument but this too fails.

Can I add multiple `s3` paths to a Glue Crawler with Terraform? I can make this happen through the AWS console but this needs to be done using infrastructure as code.

Comment: I've not used Glue but from a quick look at the docs it looks like you can just repeat the `s3_target` block for each path. On my phone right now so can't test it to make this a proper answer.

Comment: Adding three more `s3_target` blocks to the glue crawler resource allowed me to add all four of my buckets to the crawler. I had reviewed the glue docs but saw nowhere that led me to believe that I could replicate the `s3_target` blocks. Can you help me see what was missing? Also, can I add those blocks progrommatically based upon a variable? Feel free to add as an answer when you're back at a box; happy to accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To target additional S3 paths you can just repeat the `s3_target` block multiple times like this:

```
resource "aws_glue_crawler" "datalake_crawler" {
  database_name = "${var.glue_db_name}"
  name          = "${var.crawler_name}"
  role          = "${aws_iam_role.glue.id}" 

  s3_target {
    path = "${var.data_source_path_1}"
  }

  s3_target {
    path = "${var.data_source_path_2}"
  }
}
```

This is briefly alluded to in the [`aws_glue_crawler` resource docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/glue_crawler.html) where it [says](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/glue_crawler.html#s3_target):

> s3_target (Optional) List nested Amazon S3 target arguments. See below.

You can also see this in the [source code for the resource's schema](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/02be322e155e5cda718a3e66e6b750f242bc4132/aws/resource_aws_glue_crawler.go#L105-L108):

```golang
        "s3_target": {
            Type:     schema.TypeList,
            Optional: true,
            MinItems: 1,
```

Unfortunately, pre 0.12, you can't build this programatically directly in Terraform to loop over a list of dynamic paths and need to specify them statically.

Terraform 0.12 will introduce HCL2 which has better support for loops (other than using `count`) including [dynamic blocks](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each#dynamic-nested-blocks) which would allow you to then do something like this:

```
resource "aws_glue_crawler" "datalake_crawler" {
  database_name = var.glue_db_name
  name          = var.crawler_name
  role          = aws_iam_role.glue.id 

  dynamic "s3_target" {
    for_each = var.data_source_paths

    content {
      path = s3_target
    }
  }
}
```